# Channel network from high resolution DEM for flat areas

Tags: dem, hydrology

I'm working on channel network extraction from a LiDAR DEM (square grid max resolution 0,25 cm), and my area of study is vary flat with some part below the sea level.

I applied the classical valley recognition method with D8 and ArcGIS software but the output, I think, is not correct (the fill tool modifies a lot the DEM).

I saw there are various method like, for example, Pelletier (2013) and Clubb et al. (2014) but they seem to be created for mountain areas and I can't find many methods applicable in flat areas.

What procedure can I use?

Comment: Not that it answers your question but QGIS offers a number of different flow accumulation algorithms. Maybe something other than the D8 will produce better results.   https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&prev=_t&sl=auto&tl=en&u=http://www.sigterritoires.fr/%3Fp%3D538

Comment: In addition to considering the flow algorithm, I'd suggest using a different DEM preproccessing tool that may be better served for flat areas.  Something like Fill Sinks Plus, discussed here: https://community.esri.com/thread/66980.  Or WhiteBox GAT's DepressionBreach tool.

Comment: Also, I've not seen this done on flat areas, but instead of using a flow direction based channel mapping procedure to derive stream channel, perhaps try a pattern recognition technique like geomorphons: http://sil.uc.edu/geom/app?  Again, unsure if this would be appropriately applied in flat areas, since not sure if possible to distinguish channel patterns in a completely flat area.  From my experience, it is not a simple thing to map accurate channels on flat areas.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I'm trying with Whitebox GAT DepressionBreach tool and D-infinity but I'm not very confidenti also in this solution. Probably I will turn my approach in something more geomorphic-based but It's a brand new world for me